# MATLAB to C++: csvread() not supported by MATLAB Coder

Tags: c++, matlab, csv, matlab-coder

I need to port a MATLAB script, which uses `.csv`s to read and write configs and data with `csvread()`, to C++.

Obvious choice was to use the Coder app in MATLAB but `csvread()` is not supported by Coder.

What would be the best course of action to get the conversion going?

I tried reading the file via `fileread()` or `fread()` to parse the file in MATLAB but functions like `textscan()` aren't supported by Coder either.

Also it seems like `coder.ceval()` cannot return arrays - at least the manual says so - how would a parser have to look like in C++? I was planning on returning a nested vector.

Comment: *I was planning on returning a nested vector* FWIW, don't do that.  ND vectors should no be used as they lack data locality.  If you need a ND vector, wrap a 1D vector in a class and use math to pretend it has multiple dimensions (or just get a library that already does this)

Comment: Here is a really simple 2D example of what Nathan's talking about][(https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076668/4581301)

Comment: Did you consider using the MATLAB Compiler instead? No code generation required but you can still share your Software with users who don't have a MATLAB license.

Comment: @Daniel i did, but it would be my last option since i will need the output / results of some of the scripts in my cpp code going forward (e.g. one of the scripts does image comparison on per-pixel basis and returns the likeliness percentage - i will need to use this likeliness value in further calculations)

Comment: You can use MATLAB Compiler to produce a C++ shared library so you can use the results in your other code: https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/gs/create-a-cc-mwarray-application.html

Comment: @Daniel and Ryan: i was successful in using the shared library approach in my limited testing, but it turns out the target environment doesn't allow for an mcr installation (it's a linux compute cluster, i'm developing on windows, so here's another hurdle lol), which would be required by both the mxarray as well as the new data api - please correct me if i'm wrong on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're set on using Coder, once you read the file, you can use a combination of the MATLAB function `strtok` and a `coder.ceval` call to the C `sscanf` to do the parsing. My answer [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/231663-how-do-i-get-the-user-s-input-in-a-matlab-standalone-executeable) shows an example of doing this for parsing CSV data.

**Data**

```
1, 221.34
2, 125.36
3, 98.27
```

**Code**

```matlab
function [idx, temp, outStr] = readCsv(fname)
% Example of reading in 8-bit ASCII data in a CSV file with FREAD and
% parsing it to extract the contained fields.
NULL = char(0);
f = fopen(fname, 'r');
N = 3;
fileString = fread(f, [1, Inf], '*char'); % or fileread
outStr = fileString;
% Allocate storage for the outputs
idx = coder.nullcopy(zeros(1,N,'int32'));
temp = coder.nullcopy(zeros(1,N));
k = 1;
while ~isempty(fileString)
    % Tokenize the string on comma and newline reading an
    % index value followed by a temperature value
    dlm = [',', char(10)];
    [idxStr,fileString] = strtok(fileString, dlm);
    fprintf('Parsed index: %s\n', idxStr);
    [tempStr,fileString] = strtok(fileString, dlm);
    fprintf('Parsed temp: %s\n', tempStr);
    % Convert the numeric strings to numbers
    if coder.target('MATLAB')
        % Parse the numbers using sscanf
        idx(k) = sscanf(idxStr, '%d');
        temp(k) = sscanf(tempStr, '%f');
    else
        % Call C sscanf instead.  Note the '%lf' to read a double.
        coder.ceval('sscanf', [idxStr, NULL], ['%d', NULL], coder.wref(idx(k)));
        coder.ceval('sscanf', [tempStr, NULL], ['%lf', NULL], coder.wref(temp(k)));
    end
    k = k + 1;
end
fclose(f);
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I actually have seen the topic you linked to but skipped it for some reason.

i managed to adapt it to my needs, however, `coder.wref(temp(k))` throws `Dimensions of arrays being concatenated are not consistent.` I'll open a new topic on this one.

Comment: also just a heads-up for anyone stumbling upon this: linear indexing (e.g. `temp(k)`) results in the csv being written row-major, so the result might need to be transposed, as was in my case.